# Know existing producers for a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

In a Kafka server, I want to know all the producers which are sending data to a Kafka topic. Is there a way to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Toby This question doesn't require any code. It would be a shell command, if anything

Comment: What data are you even expecting? Servers? Usernames? Application IDs?

Comment: @cricket, I think if Vinay was looking for a simple command, [sf] or [su] would be a more appropriate place to ask.  Since this is Stack Overflow, we need to at least have the skeleton of the program this will be part of.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible. A Kafka broker doesn't have any information about connected producers even because the producer could not provide any identity information on connection; for this reason there is no command line tool for doing that.

Comment: The cient-id is optional in the producer.

Comment: It's possible if using Kerberos or some other auth where clients do identify and have ability to be audited

Comment: Up to which version of Kafka this answer is valid for?

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: @AnkitBatra Yes