# Getting Kafka usage details

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to find ways to get current usage statistics for my kafka cluster. I am looking to collect following information:

1. Number of topics in kafka cluster
2. Number of partitions per kafka broker
3. Number of active consumers and producers
4. Number of client connections per kafka broker
5. Number of messages on each partition, size of disk etc.
6. Lagging replicas, consumer lag etc.
7. Active consumer groups

Any other statistics that can and should be collected, currently I am looking at collecting the above stats.

I can get 1 and 2 using zookeeper utilities but I am lost on rest. I have looked at mbeans in Jconsole but didn't find anything about above. I also tried JmxTool to get these mbeans using regex based expression but that also didn't work.

I am using Kafka v2.1 and using new consumer api so zookeeper doesn't have any information about consumers.

Any pointers would be great help!

Comment: 3. Not sure if you can get 'active' consumers but the kafka api does support getting a list of groups and their current offset. 4, and 5 un sure. 6. Kafka api does allow getting the lag per group. 7 and 3 seem like the same question. A tool I like to use for getting some the info you described is https://github.com/fgeller/kt. Another thing you might want to checkout is a new tool linkden just open sourced https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2019/02/introducing-kafka-cruise-control-frontend

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager or https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control to get this information.

There are scripts under $KAFKA_HOME/bin which can help you.

> Number of topics in kafka cluster

./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list

> Number of partitions per kafka broker

./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe

> Number of messages on each partition, size of disk etc.

./kafka-log-dirs.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

> Lagging replicas, consumer lag etc.

./kafka-consumer-group.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group $GROUP_NAME --describe

> Active consumer groups
>   Number of active consumers and producers

You can't get active producer.
[Know existing producers for a kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153302/know-existing-producers-for-a-kafka-topic)

./kafka-consumer-group.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list

> Number of client connections per kafka broker

./

Comment: You can get active producers with a Kerberos enabled cluster and using Hortonworks Stream Manager thing