# Kafka - finding producers of a topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Given a topic,Is there anyway to find out all the producers generating the messages to the topic?

I went through the documentation, I couldn't find a direct way to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153302/know-existing-producers-for-a-kafka-topic , this would help

Comment: Try looking into Stream Messaging Manager

Comment: it seems there is no command :-(